# How to add titles and legends to a PDF created from PNG images in R?

Tags: r

I loaded many PNG files in R and arranged them into a 6-image-per-page PDF, now I would like to add a title to each page, as well as a legend for rows and columns. Those would be basically the following variables: `tf`, `version` and `revcomp`, and possibly data from the `fullrecords` dataframe. Can I add them from the following code or should I think of another way to do it?

```
pngFiles  <- list()
for (tf in row.names(fullrecords)) {
  for (revcomp in c("", "_rc")) {
    for (version in 2:4) {
      logo <- readPNG(paste0("v", version, ".0/PSSM-Dataset_v", version, ".0.tab_logo_", tf, revcomp, ".png"))
      pngFiles[[paste0(tf, version, revcomp)]] <- rasterGrob(logo)
    }
  }
}
ml <- marrangeGrob(pngFiles, nrow=3, ncol=2)
ggsave("file.pdf", ml)
```

The output is a PDF of many pages looking like this:

[image: PDF output]

Comment: If this is base graphics, you can do it with a crafty `layout`. If this is `grid`-based (`ggplot2`, `lattice`, ...), then search for combining plots and top them all with a text-only. Or (my preference) use R markdown with chapter titles or headers.

Comment: Rmarkdown would be a great option, but can't seem to include it inside code chunks